# There is no scroll bar on my website, I cannot scroll with the scroll wheel

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, scrollbar

i am making a website and i have noticed that i cannot scroll using the scroll wheel on a mouse. I can use two-finger scrolling on my chromebook but not the scroll wheel on my pc. The issue is with both of the browsers i use; firefox and chrome.

Thanks in advance, Liam

css:

```
  header {
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

footer {
  clear: both;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
  position: relative;
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #3D3D3D;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0)
}

.navwrap{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.name-logo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #4BD150;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  float: left;
  background-color: #f5fafa;
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  border-right: 4px solid #F5f5f5;
  width: calc(65% - 4px);
  z-index: 1;
  height: 300px;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 30%;
  float: right;
  background-color: #f5fafa;
  height: 300px;
}

.social {
  width: 30%;
  float: right;
}

.social-icon {
  float: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  width: 35px;
}

#facebook {
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.coppyright {
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 25px;
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.name {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.helper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.logo {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  white-space:nowrap;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 20%;
  margin-left: 20%;
}
.logo-img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#nav {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  height: 50px;
}
#nav li {
  float: left;
  font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 15px ;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 11px;
  text-decoration: none;    
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;
}
#nav li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #333333; 
  height: 39px;
}

#home {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:regular,bold&amp;subset=Latin">
<title>Hackapi Mockup</title>
</head>
<!--This is where the navbar and splash title goes-->
<body><header>
<div class="navwrap">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul id="nav">
      <li id="home"><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>  
</div>
  <div class="name-logo">
    <div class="logo">
      <span class="helper"></span>
      <img class="logo-img" src="https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/821x224q90/674/hloZoz.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<!--Main content and sidebar-->

  <div class="content">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">

  </div>

<!--Here is where all extra links, coppyrights and social media links go-->
<footer>
  <div class="coppyright">
    <h4>Coppyright Hackapi 2014</h4>
  </div>
  <div calss="social">
    <img id="facebook" class="social-icon" src="https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/128x128q90/538/Kk3S3f.png">
    <img id="twitter" class="social-icon" src="https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/128x128q90/913/xP6ctI.png">
    <img id="gplus" class="social-icon" src="https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/128x128q90/536/nkHuql.png">
    <img id="ytube" class="social-icon" src="https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/128x128q90/906/Sct7fy.png">
  </div>
</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Please provide some code instead of a link to your site so this question can stay useful when the content of your site changes. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @X.L.Ant I have revised my question with the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it is due to this style:

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

You have to remove overflow:hidden as it is preventing the scrollbars from showing.

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
overflow: auto;
OR
overflow-y: auto;
```

on body {}